# How to add background only to title frame and an other only to the last frame?

Tags: beamer, titles, backgrounds

I just want to add a background only in the `beamer` title page. I can add it in the `.tex` as follows:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{img/bg-first.pdf}
}
```

But I don't want the above command in the `.tex`, but in the `.sty` files. Thanks for pointing me out how I can add the above command in the `.sty` files.

Please find the `.sty` and `.tex` files below (all of them are quite simple).

---

### `main.sty`

```
\mode<presentation>

\DeclareOptionBeamer{titlepage}{\PassOptionsToPackage{titlepage=#1}{beamertheme-Inner}}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\usetheme{Inner}
\usetheme{Outer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\mode
<all>
```

---

### `inner.sty`

```
\mode<presentation>


\DeclareOptionBeamer{titlepage}{\def\beamer@titlepage{#1}}

\defbeamertemplate*{titlepage}
{
  \begin{center}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty
    \else
      \vskip2ex
      \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\insertsubtitle
    \fi
    \ifx\insertauthor\@empty
    \else
      \vskip2ex
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \fi
    \ifx\insertdate\@empty
    \else
      \vskip2ex
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate%
    \fi
  \end{center}
  \vfill
}
```

---

### `.tex` file

```
\usetheme{Afnic}

\title{An example theme for \LaTeX{} Beamer}
\author{Sandoche}
\date{February 29, 2012}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
   \begin{frame}
       \frametitle{Outline}
       \tableofcontents[currentsection]
   \end{frame}
}
```

Comment: This is the first time i am hearing about tikz :-). Which tikz code are you referring to ?

Comment: Yes it didn't work.

Comment: I changed the title a little …

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could check for the frame number:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber=1%
        % On title page
    \fi%
}
```

You may extend this to set thing to all frames except the title:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber=1%
        % On title page
    \else%
            % Other frames background
    \fi%
}
```

---

### Extended version

As requested a version that also checks for the last frame. We use `etoolbox` to enable nested if statements.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
   \ifnumequal{\c@framenumber}{1}{%
      % First frame
      \color{red!50}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}
   }{%
      \ifnumequal{\c@framenumber}{\inserttotalframenumber}{
         % Last frame
         \color{orange!50}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}
      }{%
         % Other frames
         \color{green!50}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}
      }%
   }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frame{1}

\frame{2}

\frame{3}

\frame{4}
\end{document}
```

[image: different backgrounds]

`\c@framenumber` is the counter of the current frame and `\inserttotalframenumber` holds the number of the last frame. Certanly one can omit the `Other frames` part

Comment: Simply great you are. I have spent nearly one and a half day on this. Just not to disturb you too much, can i do the similar for the last page in the case where the frame number is not known. Thanks again.

Comment: @sandoche: I’ll have a look at that soon :-)

Comment: @sandoche: I added an extended version …

Comment: Sorry for the delay as i was in holidays. Impeccable as the French say. What should i do to give you full marks.

Comment: @sandoche: I’m not sure what you mean with “full mark” but if my answer answers your question u may upvote it and click the gray check mark to accept my answer.

Comment: With TeX Live 2013 on Ubuntu 14.04 this solution assigns the same background to all slides.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa: Sorry I can’t reproduce it … neither with TeX Live 2013 nor with ’14 on OS X. Maybe you can try to update your system …

Answer (score 4):

The solution of Tobi has some significant disadvantages. It only works when the titlepage is actually the first frame and also produces a problem when not using the titlepage. A somewhat better solution is using the `\AddToShipoutPictureFG*` command of `eso-pic` inside the `\setbeamertemplate{title page}` command. So the code for the askers `inner.sty` would be:

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{img/bg-first.pdf}}
  \begin{center}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty
    \else
      \vskip2ex
      \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\insertsubtitle
    \fi
    \ifx\insertauthor\@empty
    \else
      \vskip2ex
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \fi
    \ifx\insertdate\@empty
    \else
      \vskip2ex
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate%
    \fi
  \end{center}
  \vfill
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have an issue using \AddToShipoutPictureFG if I display notes on a second screen. The exact command is: \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}. The background is on the note and not on the titlepage now!