# My last frame should be n-1 slide

Tags: beamer

I have set in my `.sty` file as follows (to have a predefined background in my last slide):

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
 \ifnumequal{\c@framenumber}{\inserttotalframenumber}{
         % Last frame
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{img/bg-last.pdf}
      }
}
```

The issue is the last frame in the `.tex` file overlaps on the above background. I want my last frame in the `.tex` file to be `n-1` slide.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you correctly, but why can't you just add another (empty) frame (`\frame{}`) at the end of your presentation?

Comment: Yes, thats an idea. But it's not so clean.

Comment: BTW: The given code doesn't work out of the box: You need to load [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), and `\ifnumequal` has four arguments, so a `{}` is missing after the closing brace in l. 5. The full working code can be found in the question [How to add background only to title frame and an other only to the last frame?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46382/3323).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't fully understand why this should be done automatically, but you can simply add the final frame with `\AtEndDocument`. Like this, you don't have to check for the last frame with `\ifnumequal{\c@framenumber}{\inserttotalframenumber}{...}{...}` either, instead you can use `\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{...}` in a group to define a custom background for the last (otherwise empty) slide.

#### Example code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\AtEndDocument{%
{%
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{img/bg-last.pdf}%
  }%
  \frame{}%
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

To incorporate this into your `.sty` file, just use the `\AtEndDocument` call (ll. 2-8).

Comment: You got it right. This is what i wanted.