# Beamer: define a backgroung color for the "part page" frames

Tags: beamer, titles, backgrounds

I'm trying to make a .sty template, but I cannot figure out how to define a dedicated background canvas for the "part page" frames.

Here ([How to add background only to title frame and an other only to the last frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46353/how-to-add-background-only-to-title-frame-and-an-other-only-to-the-last-frame)) is a solution for when it is possible to characterize the background depending on the frame number, but it cannot be applied in my situation.

So is there a way to test the "type" of frame? (like "title page", "part page", ...). If yes, it means I can do the same as the solution to sandoche's problem. If not, can  anybody think of a workaround?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, the background canvas is drawn before the actual contents of the frame are read. So in `\frame{\partpage}`, the background is drawn before beamer sees the `\partpage` and can realize that the frame is a part page.

If you want a `\frame{\partpage}` immediately after every `\part{}`, then you can simply hook into `\AtBeginPart`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginPart{%
    {%  start a group to keep the template change local
        \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
            \color{red!50}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}%
        }%
        \frame{\partpage}%
    }%  end group
}

\begin{document}
\part{The first part}
\frame{...}
\frame{...}
\part{The second part}
\frame{...}
\frame{...}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

The solution offered by Caramdir does not allow to get a different background color for a part page when entering

```
\begin{frame}
  \partpage
\end{frame}
```

Suppose that the background of a part page is given by the background color of the part-title (this can easily be adapted).  Here is the trick.  We first define a new page style which will be used for part-pages.  This page style is then added in the part-page template.

For convenience, we also add a key so that the background color can easily be inserted using the `bgcolor` key.

---

Here is a complete example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@navigation@partpage{%
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{use=part title,bg=part title.bg}%
  \@nameuse{ps@navigation}}
\addtobeamertemplate{part page}{\thispagestyle{navigation@partpage}}{}
\define@key{beamerframe}{bgcolor}[]{%
  \ifx#1\@empty\else\setbeamercolor{part title}{bg=#1}\fi}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{part title}{bg=pink} % default color

\begin{document}

\part{First Part}

\begin{frame}
  \partpage
\end{frame}

\part{Second Part}

\begin{frame}[bgcolor=yellow]
  \partpage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

The first part-page has the default pink background color and the second one has a yellow background color.  Another way to modify the background color in the previous example is via the `\setbeamercolor`:

```
\setbeamercolor{part title}{bg=yellow}
\begin{frame}
  \partpage
\end{frame}
```

Comment: @Caramdir: Here is a more flexible solution.