# multiple slides with textblocks defined in preamble

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

I have a set of slide backgrounds produced by a designer, each one with different regions for content insertion.

I am calling each background calling

```
{\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics{slides-02b.jpg}}
```

before each slide, depending on the background I want. And, in each slide, I use one or more textblocks to include the content in the desired positions.

My questions are 2:

1) is it possible to define each slide type in the preamble and just call them as needed in each frame, with using the usebackgroundtemplate at each slide?

2) is it possible to also define specific sites in each slide, for text insertion, in the preamble? For example for "slide-1" I would have "text-site-1" and "text-site-2", with coordinates previously defined in the preamble, in a way I do not have to the textblock command with coordinates several times along my tex file?

Using the [How to add background only to title frame and an other only to the last frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46353/how-to-add-background-only-to-title-frame-and-an-other-only-to-the-last-frame) proposal I was not able to include the background image, and it is not clear to me how could I define the textblocks.

Thanks in advance,

Hugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting point for first question could be:

```
\newenvironment{slideA}{%
    \bgroup\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics{example-image-A}}
    \begin{frame}}{\end{frame}\egroup}
```

The problem with this solution is that options for `frames` are not used.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{slideA}{%
    \bgroup\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics{example-image-A}}
    \begin{frame}}{\end{frame}\egroup}

\newenvironment{slideB}{%
    \bgroup\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics{example-image-B}}
    \begin{frame}}{\end{frame}\egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{slideA}
Test
\end{slideA}

\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\begin{slideB}
Test
\end{slideB}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, Ignasi, simple and easy, worked very well, thanks :) could you think in a way to incude text block fields in each slide? No more than two textblocks, with coordinates established in the preamble, perhaps within the newenvironment?